# Como pegar o caminho do diretório

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Estou usando WinForm e tentando salvar uma string com o SaveFileDialog mas não consigo passar o diretório escolhido no SaveFileDialog para a função do System.IO.File.WriteAllLines;

```
        private void saveCategoriesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] SaveString = new string[100];
        SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog();
        SFD.Filter = "Categories Files (.ctg)|*.ctg";
        SFD.Title = "Save a Categories file";
        SFD.ShowDialog();

         if (SFD.FileName == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a name for the file", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            SaveString[0] = tamanho.ToString();
            for(int i=1;i<=tamanho;i++)
            {
                SaveString[i] = "\"" + KeysValues[i] + "\",\"" + CategoriesValues[i] + "\"";
            }
            SFD.DefaultExt = ".ctg";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(, SaveString);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caio, o que você procura é a classe [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), podendo ser usado da seguinte forma

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(SFD.FileName);

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileInfo.DirectoryName, SaveString);
```

Nesse caso o `fileInfo.DirectoryName` retorna o diretório do arquivo selecionado pelo `SaveFileDialog`